# how to gray out node images in a vis.js network

Tags: vis.js

I've been able to highlight different parts of a vis.js network by utilizing the  mechanism shown in the vis.js documentation examples. However,I wonder if we can get the same sort of effect when images are used for representing network nodes -as opposed to basic node shapes- (a straightforward 'coloring' of the nodes, as in the examples, does not gray out the images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of the vis.js network module. Unfortunately there is no shortcut here. You'll have to generate b&w images of your images and change the image option to the greyscale image.

Another idea is to use the opacity, that does work for the images. If you have any more questions, please post them on our github page. We get emails from the issues and we like to use that to keep track of questions.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for answering! I may follow up on github for details on the opacity issue.